NextJS custom server with typescript not working
I am trying to use custom server with NextJS along with typescript. For that, I need to call nextjs createServer function.
This is working properly if I use require terminology:
const next=require('next');
const app=next({dev});
console.log(next);
// console log result: [function createServer]

But if I use import terminology:
import next from 'next';
const app=next({dev});
console.log(next);
// console log result: [function createServer]

This gives error
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("/next")' has no call signatures.

Not sure why typescript is throwing this error when both methods are returning createServer function.

you can modify server.js to server.mjs
server.mjs


import { createServer } from "node:http";
import next from "next";




For me it worked the following way (in a CommonJS project with Next v14):
import next from "next";

// https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server
const app = next({ dev: true });
app.prepare().then(() => { });

In an ESM project it is currently not possible to import next because of this bug: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46078
